# Adding Jar files to Maven

Tags: maven, jar

I have started to work on maven project recently.
The piece of code I am writing needs JAR files that are not a part of the project.
When I add the JARS TO THE build path and use a mvn clean install, the build is failing with errors saying that the classes that were supposed to be in the jar were not found.

Is there anything that i am missing? 
Is there a different way to add the JAR's in maven projects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the JARs are already hoisted in some public Maven repositories, add them to the `<dependency>` section in the `pom.xml` . You may have to configure the address of these public Maven repositories in the  `<repositories>` section in the `pom.xml` in order to cause Maven can connect them.

Otherwise , you have to use the `install` command to include these JARs into the your local repository and then add their `<dependency>` section in the `pom.xml`

The command to install the JARs into your local repository:

```
mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.abc -DartifactId=XXXXX
-Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/jars
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you don't understand how Maven works. You don't add jars to the build path, you declare them in the pom, and let Maven download to the local drive, and it adds it to the build path for you. I would recommend you read [this 5 minute intro](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html), and understand how the dependency management works.